# How to implement sql left join in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Suppose I have a table M which is :
[[1 A],[2 B],[3 C]]
 and another table N:
[[3 a],[2 b]]

Applying a left join(using 1st column in table M as the primary key),will give the resulting table as:
[[1 A],[2 B b],[3 C a]]

How can this be implemented using javascript?

Comment: Im pretty sure it cant. Javascript is a client side language unless used with something like nodeJS and even then it is used with a noSQL database such as mongo

Comment: @Janpan That's not what the OP was asking. They are asking for the **behavior** of a left join

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions. One of which is mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017616/javascript-optimal-way-to-join-2-sets-of-objects-like-in-sql

Comment: @mhodges wrong, the OP specifically asks and I quote "How can this be implemented using javascript?"

Comment: @Janpan Verbiage !== intent. I can read what the post says, but the intention is "I can do a left join in sql, but I am working with javascript arrays. How can I achieve the same functionality in javascript as I have in sql?" Also, to your first comment, nodeJS is not limited to noSQL databases...

Comment: @Janpan That's like questions asking "How can classes be implemented using javascript?" or "How can static typing be implemented using javascript?".. They want to know how to replicate the functionality -- not to somehow access features from another language/architecture.

Comment: @mhodges, I disagree. The question specifically asks how an SQL left join can be implemented using javascript. And to my knowledge, it cant. In my honost opinion, it is not my job to fish out what the OP REALLY meant. The OP's question should be clear and to the point without having any hidden intent. I am sorry if I did not answer the question, I was simply trying to provide my answer with my understanding of the question.

Comment: I just wanted to know how can a left join be implemented using javascript if I have two 2D arrays and I need a third array which has the result of left join of those 2 given arrays.

Comment: @SoumyaSharma, Thanks, I understand what you need. I think it would be better in that case to make use of a Jaascript object and assign key value pairs to the object. Each key can be an array and you can push values to each key/array by pushing values into the key e.g. endObj.col3.push(C) and endObj.col3.push(a). So in short, you can loop through your values in each array and if the keys match, you can push the value of that key into your result object. 

I would write a better formatted answer if I could, but it seems that I cannot write an answer to this post anymore.

Comment: @Janpan Yes I followed the same approach and the code is working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Janpan Due to their lack of knowledge in the subject area, many posters do not know the correct verbiage or keywords to say to be explicitly and technically accurate with their questions; so  yes, It **IS** our job to parse out what the OP is asking for, based on context and what makes sense. If you feel the question is unclear, that is what the downvote button is for. Downvote the question and leave a comment asking the OP to clarify/rephrase/give more details.