# Loop through list of maps to filter map key-values using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dictionary, alasql

How to loop through list of maps to filter out SearchMap key-values from below List having map of records using JS?

### Map

```
var searchMap = new Map()
searchMap.set("ed_mood", "strong")
searchMap.set("ed_target_audience", "Expert")
searchMap.set("ed_clip_type", "intro")
```

### List

```
var master_data =
[
    {ed_mood: "Light", ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: "Novice", ed_clip_type: "Basic"},
    {ed_mood: "Light", ed_rating: 5, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Q&A"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 8, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Intro"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 7, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Q&A"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "intro"}
]
```

**Note**: To filter out record I am using AlaSql but it doesn't give expected result. Any other JS way to filter map to list of maps?

```
var filter_result = [];
searchMap.forEach(function(value, key){
    var data  = alasql(`select * from ? where ${key} like ?`,[master_data, `%${value}%`]);
    $.each(data, (i) => filter_result.push(data[i]));
});
```

### Expected Result

```
[
   {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 8, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Intro"},
   {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "intro"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code `filters` `master_data` to only `return` `Objects` that match every `param` in `searchMap`.

See [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [`Map.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries), [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`String.toLowercase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) for more info.

```js
// Search Map.
const searchMap = new Map([
  ['ed_mood', 'strong'],
  ['ed_target_audience', 'Expert'],
  ['ed_clip_type', 'intro']
])

// Master Data.
const master_data = [
  {ed_mood: 'Light', ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: 'Novice', ed_clip_type: 'Basic'},
  {ed_mood: 'Light', ed_rating: 5, ed_target_audience: 'Expert', ed_clip_type: 'Q&A'},
  {ed_mood: 'Strong', ed_rating: 8, ed_target_audience: 'Expert', ed_clip_type: 'Intro'},
  {ed_mood: 'Strong', ed_rating: 7, ed_target_audience: 'Expert', ed_clip_type: 'Q&A'},
  {ed_mood: 'Strong', ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: 'Expert', ed_clip_type: 'intro'}
]

// Output.
const output = 
  
  // Filter master_data for Objects that include every searchpoint.
  master_data.filter((datapoint) =>
   
  // Destructuring assignment + Map.entries to reveal searchMap entries.
  [...searchMap.entries()].every((searchpoint) =>
  
  // Object.entries() to reveal datapoint entries. 
  // JSON.stringify + toLowerCase() for normalization.
  JSON.stringify(Object.entries(datapoint)).toLowerCase().includes(JSON.stringify(searchpoint).toLowerCase())))


// Log.
console.log(output)
```

Comment: isn't this too much code for very little work. I think in such a case, expressive code would do good then desriptive.
Although for the understanding part, good to go!

Also, this is too much computation, stringifying every entry and using String.includes to check if the value of the entry is present, that is an *overkill•.

Comment: The code was originally `1 line`. I split it into `3` and added `comments` to help the asker understand what's going on. `JSON.stringify()` cheaply normalises the data for efficient comparison. Please feel free to post a more terse / efficient solution if you believe one exists 

Comment: I'd rather not stringify.
I'd make a 
`searchMatchers = Object.keys(searchMap).map(function(data){
        return [data,searchMap[data]];
    });`

Then, 
`const endResult = master_data.filter(dataObj => {
    return searchMatchers.every(([key, value]) => {
        return dataObj[key]  === value;
    })
})`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are concatenating the conditions using (implicitly) the `OR` operator. Your expected result suggests that you should use the `AND` operator.

You could build your SQL command first and then execute it using [AlaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) (just a suggestion, you introduced me to AlaSQL :-) )

```js
var searchMap = new Map();
searchMap.set("ed_mood", "strong");
searchMap.set("ed_target_audience", "Expert");
searchMap.set("ed_clip_type", "intro");

var master_data =
[
    {ed_mood: "Light", ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: "Novice", ed_clip_type: "Basic"},
    {ed_mood: "Light", ed_rating: 5, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Q&A"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 8, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Intro"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 7, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Q&A"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "intro"}
];

var command = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE";
var values = [];

searchMap.forEach(function(value, key){
 command += ` ${key} LIKE ? AND`;
 values.push('%' + value);
});

//Removing the last "AND"
command = command.substring(0, command.length -4);

var filter_result = alasql(command, [master_data, ...values]);

console.log(filter_result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.4.5/alasql.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Solution without AlaSQL

Using ES6, your code could be:

```js
var searchMap = new Map();
searchMap.set("ed_mood", "strong");
searchMap.set("ed_target_audience", "Expert");
searchMap.set("ed_clip_type", "intro");

var master_data =
[
    {ed_mood: "Light", ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: "Novice", ed_clip_type: "Basic"},
    {ed_mood: "Light", ed_rating: 5, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Q&A"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 8, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Intro"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 7, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "Q&A"},
    {ed_mood: "Strong", ed_rating: 10, ed_target_audience: "Expert", ed_clip_type: "intro"}
];

var filter_result = master_data.filter(function(x) {
    for (var [key, value] of searchMap) {
        //Change the comparison to fit your needs
    
        // Condition to handle null , undefined and ''(blank) values
        if (x[key] !== null && typeof x[key] !== 'undefined' && x[key] !== '') {
            if (x[key].toLowerCase() !== value.toLowerCase()) return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

console.log(filter_result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.4.5/alasql.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need to reference alasql in the second snippet. It currently results in "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." By removing the reference to `alasql`, there is no error in the output. For the first snippet, alas I have no work-around. Sorry! (It most likely works just fine in jsFiddle.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's `filter` method here.

In your case, you will do:

```
const result = _filter(master_data, {
  ed_mood: 'strong',
  ed_target_audience: 'expert',
  ed_clip_type: 'intro'
});
```

Read more about it on [lodash/filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#filter)