# how to loop and convert an array of objects to an object with key value pair

Tags: javascript

I have an Array of Objects something like this

```
[
  {name: "John", country: "USA", revision: 1},
  {name: "Mark", country: "England", revision: 0},
  {name: "Bruce", country: "France", revision: 1}
]
```

I want to convert it into an object with key value pair with name key, like this

```
{
  John : {name: "John", country: "USA", revision: 1},
  Mark : {name: "Mark", country: "England", revision: 0},
  Bruce : {name: "Bruce", country: "France", revision: 1}
}
```

This is what I have done but it does not seems to work

```
let component = contents.reduce(((content, current}) => {
    content[name] = current;
    return content;
}), {});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A simple `for` loop should be enough to get the expected output.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271554/loop-through-list-of-maps-to-filter-map-key-values-using-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.reduce` func.

```js
const input = [
  {name: "John", country: "USA", revision: 1},
  {name: "Mark", country: "England", revision: 0},
  {name: "Bruce", country: "France", revision: 1}
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, {name, ...item}) => {
  acc[name] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You may use destructuring of `.reduce()` arguments: `input.reduce((acc, {name, ...rest}) => (acc[name] = item, acc), {})`